# particular element from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to try function data alert value fine but data.id1,data.vh_stock not getting value please share valuable idea...

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tanktype').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/Mechanical_rdirecived/viewtankstock"; ?>', { dropdownValue: id }, 
    function(data){                
        alert('ajax completed. Response:  '+data);//msg=ajax completed. Response:    {"vh_stock":"600","id1":"4"}null
        alert('ajax completed. Response:  '+data.vh_stock);//msg=ajax completed. Response:    undefined
        alert($(this).data("vh_stock"));    
      },)
    });
});
```

Comment: parse data as data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: please edit my code sir and share me...

Comment: What is in the `data` variable? If you're not sure, use `console.log()` and see what turns up. If it's JSON, Devsi has already given you the solution.

Comment: I cannot interpret the question, please improve on grammar and spelling of your question.

Comment: this is json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print log in your browser console, alert instead -

```
alert('ajax completed. Response: ' + data); // Not
console.log(data); // Do
```

Then check your data array in console.

Comment: data not show   undefined

Comment: then copy/paste your data here